# Genuine Apple Air Pods Pro is no longer recognized as genuine

Tags: airpods

I bought my Air Pods Pro from an official Apple store, and after one year I got this message! and the Air Pods become very annoying like: one of the pairs does not charge and the second does not hold charge for more than 1 minute and i keeps disconnecting ! I suspect that this is a software thing!

How isn't it recognized as a genuine part ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Detection of counterfeit AirPods and this message was only added in iOS 16. It taking a year to show just lines up with the recent release of this feature.

Contact Apple Support at https://getsupport.apple.com/ or take your AirPods to an Apple Store for investigation.